# installing ubuntu 14.04.3. LTS

Tags: partitioning

My laptop configuration  is intel i7 (2nd generation) 64 bit, win 7 service pack 1, with 6 GB RAM and 1 TB HDD (with two partition C (436 GB) and D (547 GB)).
C drive contains windows OS.
D drive contains all the data.

I don't want win 7 but want to retain all the data in Partition D.
when I start installing ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS using somethingelse option. I get the following partiton table
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1 ntfs 104 MB (Windows 7 loader)
/dev/sda2 ntfs 430570 MB ...... likely to be C drive (partition)
/dev/sda3 ntfs 546537 MB ...... likely to be D drive (partition)
/dev/sda4 ntfs 22988 MB   (Windows Recovery Environment (loader))

so how do I install ubuntu (i.e replacing/removing Windows 7, and also keeping the data of partition D)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, but here is the most clean and proper one ...

1. Copy all data from the D partition to an external location (hard disk/USB disk).
2. Boot from Ubuntu installation media and select Try Ubuntu without installing.
3. When the Ubuntu desktop appears, press the Windows key and type GParted.
4. Open GParted and delete all partitions - create 3 new partitions (Note below).
5. Close GParted - click on Install Ubuntu - when asked - choose Something else.
6. Select the ext4 partition you created before - choose **/** (root) as mount point.
7. Start installing Ubuntu and when finished boot the Ubuntu operating system.
8. Copy back the data you transferred to the external drive to the ntfs partition.

Note :

Create a new partition and format it with ext4 - choose a size that fits your needs.
Create a new partition and format it with linux-swap - the size should match RAM.
Create a new partitiion and format it with ntfs - choose a size that fits your needs.

These are my recommendations ... the advantages are a complete clean new setup
and in case you want to install Windows later, you can access your data from there.